# Push data to Soap webservice with Spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

Hi I've referred to this [link](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) for consuming a SOAP webservice.
But i'm not sure how to call the client method.

Please find my code below : 
ClientConfig.java

```
package com.exclusively.unicommerce.service;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() 
{
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.unicommerce.wsdl");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public SaleOrderClient saleorderclient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    SaleOrderClient client = new SaleOrderClient();
    client.setDefaultUri("https://link.com/services/soap/?version=1.6");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}


}
```

SaleOrderClient.java

```
public class SaleOrderClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport{

private static final String uri = "https://link.com/services/soap/?version=1.6";

public String createSaleOrder(Suborder suborder)
{
    SaleOrder saleorder = new SaleOrder();
    saleorder = setSaleOrderObject(suborder);
    CreateSaleOrderRequest request = new CreateSaleOrderRequest();
    request.setSaleOrder(saleorder);

    //PLEASE NOTE THIS Line of CODE.
    this.getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(uri,request);
    return "Pushed to Unicommerce";
}

public SaleOrder setSaleOrderObject(Suborder suborder)
{
    SaleOrder saleorder = new SaleOrder();
    saleorder.setAdditionalInfo(null);
    saleorder.setAddresses(null);
    saleorder.setCashOnDelivery(null);
    saleorder.setCFormProvided(null);
    saleorder.setChannel(null);
    saleorder.setCode(null);
    saleorder.setCurrencyCode(null);
    saleorder.setCustomerCode(null);
    saleorder.setDisplayOrderCode(null);
    saleorder.setNotificationEmail(null);
    saleorder.setNotificationMobile(null);
    saleorder.setVerificationRequired(null);
    return saleorder;
}
}
```

SuborderController.java

```
@Controller
public class SuborderController {

private String currentStatus, finalStatus,status,response;

@Autowired
private SuborderService suborderservice;

@RequestMapping(value = "/orders/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String addOrders(@RequestBody Suborder order) {
    if(order.getSuborderId() ==  null ||   order.getSuborderId().isEmpty())
        return "BAD REQUEST";
    suborderservice.addOrders(order);
    //**CALL To createSaleorder(order)**
    //response = saleorderclient.createSaleorder(order);
    return response;
}
```

Here things to note is that webservice has provided request class but no response class. Second i tried

```
  @Autowired
  SaleOrderClient saleorderclient;
```

But it threw bean not found exception.

I'm not able to understand how do i access this method.
Please help. TIA.

Comment: If the bean isn't found the configuration isn't read. Also your class is `SaleOrderClient` not `SaleorderClient`...

Comment: what changes do i need to make?

Comment: Make sure your `@Configuration` class is used. For the rest I have no idea as that information isn't available in your post.

Comment: How do i make sure that my configuration class is used? and what more information do you need?

Comment: If you have to ask that question you might want to read the reference guide (section 3 on how things work) first. Add it as a bean to your other configuration or make sure component scan is scanning the package the configuration class is in.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by adding below mentioned lines in SuborderController.java

```
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(ClientConfig.class);
    ctx.refresh();
    SaleOrderClient saleorderclient = ctx.getBean(SaleOrderClient.class);
```